# How to use gTTS in python3 on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

```
import gtts
blabla = ("Spoken text")
tts = gTTS(text=blabla, lang='en')
tts.save("test.mp3")
```

I use above code for gTTs project in raspberry pi and I had already installed gTTs in to my pi by using below code.

```
pip3 install gTTs
```

I got below error after running py script

```
$ python test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    tts = gTTS(text=blabla, lang='en')
NameError: name 'gTTS' is not defined
```

So anyone please help me about this problem.

Comment: You installed the package for python 3 using `pip3`, but you run the python script with `python test2.py` which will launch python as pyton2,7, try to run it using `python3 test2.py`.

Comment: Also it should be `from gtts import gTTS`.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd line in your code you are using the gTTS which is a property of gtts module and you can not use gTTS until you import gTTS from the gtts module. So the correct way to import gTTS is `from gtts import gTTS`. The whole code should be look like as follow;

```
from gtts import gTTS
blabla = ("Spoken text")
tts = gTTS(text=blabla, lang='en')
tts.save("test.mp3")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Got it, thank you. I tried to explain by editing my answer.